# How to check to see if you are hosting correctly on GCP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting

I recently made the jump to hosting on GCP and haven't been able to get my homepage to work. My website is made using Ruby on Rails, I've added the cname to the dns field in Google domains, and made the pages I need publicly visible in GCP, but I don't get anything. This is my first time using GCP I got it to work with AWS, but my mailing service didn't work as well with it. Any chance someone could offer some advice or insight?

[image: Google Domains]
[image: VM instance in GCP]
[image: dns instance in GCP]

Comment: While waiting for an answer, let me suggest taking a course on how websites, DNS, email, etc work. Youtube, Udemy, Pluralsight, etc all have good courses that only take a couple of hours to learn the basics. I am not trying to be rude, sometimes you need to spend time and make the effort to learn something new.

Comment: That's greatly appreciated, and I will do that. I'm good with coding, but alittle weak from not remembering too much on the networking side. So that is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I gather you have your domain parked in Google Domain. Where are your A, NS, SOA records? You need to have these configured correctly for your site to work.

For your email to work, you need to ensure your MX records are pointed to your mail server correctly.

Have you configured your DNS Zone in Google Cloud console? Check A, NS records for website to work.
Where is your MX record configured? (For emails to work)

Have you configured these?

> Google Cloud Console > Networking > Network Services > Cloud DNS
>
> Where is your mail hosted?

This elaborate [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/how-to) might help.

Ideally all ISPs provide elaborate and detail docs on configuring MX records.

More info from your end would definitely help us point you in the right direction.

Comment: Okay, my email is through the G suite, so that works now. Before I was trying to use the AWS email. Now I'm just having problems getting my website which uses a bit of Ruby on Rails to display. I keep getting that it doesn't exist. And I've added the cname per the documentations on GCP . I just don't have much of a clue what I'm doing wrong. Sorry if it seems like a lack of effort but it's really just me trying to get guidance rather than wrecking it, this project has been a year in the works.

Comment: What's the domain? Is your site configured to run on localhost? I need more details.

Comment: its custom its bradgrad.graphics, i built my site in Cloud9 but it ran on the browser via the command line.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of Google Cloud Console > Networking > Network Services > Cloud DNS

Comment: ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.

There wasnt anything in there and the step up process said to add these in.

Comment: Ok, that's NS record. Where is A records? Create an A record for domain.com and www.domain.com.

Comment: okay, Ill do that. I was able to get the mx record to work. Are the A records usually ip addresses?

Comment: Yes, the A record should point to the Public IP assigned to the Compute engine >  VM instance. However NS lookup shows your domain bradgrad.graphics is pointing to  216.239.34.21.  - Pinging the domain also resolves to the same IP. https://mxtoolbox.com/domain/bradgrad.graphics/ might give you a clear picture on the reports generated for your assistance in checking what configs are missed. On the other hand, browser returns 404 (The requested URL / was not found..) which could also mean home page not found and site might be incorrectly configured. You might want to check that as well.

Comment: Also, in addition to last comment, make sure the public IP of the Compute Engine VM instance you are pointing on the A record is Static and not Ephemeral, since in that situation IP may change. You have more details on this: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static

Comment: I think Im missing something. I am going to add the a record in. Im not sure if its because i havent connected the VM instance and the dns zone? or if its because i have to make a bucket and point to  my domain using the cname with c.storage.googleapis.com. Ive looked at tutorials and read up some and it doenst seem to work.